# Nopcommerce v2.30

Tags: .net, nopcommerce

I'm a newbie  to nopcommerce. I have downloaded Nop V2.3. The problem is,i want to edit the page but i don't know how to add plugins how to create one. How to change themes by code. How to remove plugins that i am not going to use?

How to give price tags for each product i display?

I don't even find a good tutorial to start  with nopcommerce for beginners like me. I saw your posts so thought you could help me.

I know mvc little bit and Csharp asp dot net. So if you guide me for a head start. I will be happy.

I really didn't  find any clue to start. with....to edit the nopcommerce codes.

Answer (score 2):

NopCommerce 2.0 was a complete rewrite, and all the documentation is not updated yet.
You can follow the documentation progress for the new version at http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/workitem/7653

**Removing plugins**

You can remove plugins by simply removing the ones you do not need from the Plugins folder.

**Theming**

Take a look in the Themes folder in the Nop.Web project to see how themes are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

[What are nopCommerce themes and why you should use them](http://www.nop-templates.com/blog/11/why-nopcommerce-themes)

[How to create nopCommerce themes](http://www.nop-templates.com/blog/12/how-to-create-nopcommerce-themes)

Answer (score 1):

**Add plugins**: you can use [this](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/77/default.aspx) link.
and then go to Admin site ---> Configuration ---> Plugins. There you can manage over your plugin. Or you can take existing plugin in Folder Plugins and rewrite it according to your needs as I did.

**Remove plugins**: Admin site ---> Configuration ---> Plugins --->uninstall selected plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started with nopCommerce myself and the most important thing is to have some knowlegde about the used techniques (ASP.NET MVC, Depenecy Injection, ORM (EF)).

The urls below also helped me in getting started with nopCommerce.

**Using nopCommerce**

[NopCommerce User Guide](http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/313/nopcommerce-version-230-user-guide.aspx) - Not Free BTW, but this way you support the project.

**Extending / Adjusting NopCommerce**

<strike>http://blog.csharpwebdeveloper.com/2011/09/27/cheat-sheet-for-effectively-extending-nopcommerce/</strike>
<strike>http://blog.csharpwebdeveloper.com/2011/09/10/writing-a-plugin-for-nopcommerce-2-x/</strike>
<strike>http://blog.csharpwebdeveloper.com/2011/09/10/updating-an-existing-entity-in-nopcommerce-2-0/</strike>

Update: links seem to be dead. Sorry

Comment: hi,
   Can anybody tell me how to change the contents in home menu..in Nop V2.30..that s Home Contact us, about us, i want to change this but i dont know where to do this.....may i know where i can find this contents to change for my custom  menu ..........please guide me,,,,,please....am been searching for long time.......


the demo website is here in this link i want to change the home MEnu contents to my custom contents please guide me......

http://demo.nopcommerce.com/


                     thanks in advance 


thammu

Comment: @Fresher, U can change the contents of home,contactus,aboutus in the Admin backend part,Content Management/Topic.

Answer (score 0):

U can change the contents of home,contactus,aboutus in the Admin backend part,Content Management/Topic.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding plugins**

You can add plugins by simply adding the ones you  need to the Plugins folder.Then click on install in the admin  backend.

**Theming**

Take a look in the Themes folder in the Nop.Web project to see how themes are implemented. U can change the theme in Settings/General and miscellaneous settings

U can change the contents of home,contactus,aboutus in the Admin backend part,Content Management/Topic.